# I need to write a query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Write a query to provide totals of Earned Premium and Earned Exposures
>   by company and S160 coverage code. Only include data for the year 2010
>   (1/1/2010 – 12/31/2010), company equal to GE or GG, and rated state
>   equal to CA.

Here are the tables and fields:

```
Table 1a
Earned Premium = ERND_PRM_AM
Earned Exposures = ERND_EXPSR_DY_CN
S160 Coverage Code = S160_CVRG_CD
Policy Key = PLCY_KY

Table 2a
Rated State = RTD_ST_CD
Company = CMPNY_CD
Date = SNP_DT
Policy Key = PLCY_KY
```

This is my answer - Is it correct?

```
Select 
    Table 1a.Earned Premium, Table 1a.Earned Exposures, Table 1a.S160 Coverage Code, 
    Table 2a.Company, Table 2a.Date, Table 2a.Rated State
From Table 1a
Inner Join Table 2a
On Table 1a.Policy Key=Table 2a.Policy Key
Where Date between 1/1/2010 and 12/31/2010, Company='GE' or 'GG', Rated State='CA';
```

Comment: this is incorrect answer

Comment: Have you tried your answer yourself? What are the query results?

Comment: That's not even close to being valid SQL. What is expected as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking SQL server and your table names are really 1a and 2a, then:

```
Select 
   1a.ERND_PRM_AM as [Earned Premium], 1a.ERND_EXPSR_DY_CN as [Earned Exposures], 1a.S160_CVRG_CD as [S160 Coverage Code], 
   2a.CMPNY_CD as Company, 2a.SNP_DT as [Date], 2a.RTD_ST_CD as [Rated State]
From 1a
Inner Join 2a
On 1a.PLCY_KY = 2a.PLCY_KY
Where SNP_DT between '1/1/2010' and '12/31/2010' and CMPNY_CD in ('GE', 'GG') and RTD_ST_CD = 'CA';
```

Comment: No Problem, also make sure that you mark your answer, that way other people searching can find the correct solution. Plus both of our reputations will go up. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chuck, I was doing this for a job assessment sadly I didn't get the job but I did use your code. Oh well back to the drawing board. Right? LOL.

Comment: Bummer, keep trying and good luck. Keep practicing and studying, and you easily do great.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the horribly formatted question, this is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.ERND_PRM_AM) AS 'Total Earned Premium'
,SUM(t1.ERND_EXPSR_DY_CN) AS 'Total Earned Exposures'
,t1.S160_CVRG_CD AS 'S160 Coverage Code'
,t2.CMPNY_CD AS 'Company'
FROM Table_1a t1
INNER JOIN Table_2a t2
  ON t1.PLCY_KY = t2.PLCY_KY
WHERE SNP_DT BETWEEN '20100101' AND '20101231'
  AND CMPNY_CD IN('GE','GG')
  AND RTD_ST_CD='CA'
GROUP BY t2.CMPNY_CD, t1.S160_CVRG_CD
```

This sounds like something homework related.  FYI, those type of questions are not allowed on SO.  You also give no examples of what you are expecting/sample data.